# how to transfer data from flutter module to android app

Tags: java, android, integration, android-app-bundle, flutter-module

I've created an **android app** that can receive a **full screen** from a **flutter module**. now, I want to get a text from that **flutter module** not just the full screen. so does anyone has any idea?

PS:I know how to send data from android to the flutter module! I just wanna **the reverse**.

thanks, though